# Problem with global template function

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

For some reason I can't seem to call my **global template function** in **GCC**...

Global function defined in "**globals.h**":

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> inline T1 Min (const T1 & v1, const T2 & v2)
{
    return v1 < v2 ? v1 : v2;
}
```

Call to function from class defined in "**test.h**":

```
#include "globals.h"

class Test
{
public:
    Test()
    {
        int a = 2;
        int b = 3;
        int c = Min(a, b); //error: 'Min' was not declared in this scope
        int d = ::Min(a, b); //error: '::Min' has not been declared
        int e = Min<const int, const int>(a, b); //error: expected primary-expression before 'const'
        int f = this->Min(a, b); //error: 'class Test' has no member named 'Min'
    }
};
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are you including `Test.h` in `globals.h`?

Comment: No, why would I do that?

Comment: Was just suspecting a circular inclusion. Otherwise the code should compile fine (except the last statement `int f =...`).

Comment: I suspect some other globals.h is getting included. To test, put some nonsense text in your globals.h and recompile - if you don't get a syntax error from your globals.h, it's not being included.

Comment: I get a lot of errors, because this header is included almost everywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

g++ version 4.3.4 compiles these correctly, giving an error only for the last line. See http://ideone.com/cD13Y. What version are you using?

Comment: Hm... I'm using Apple GCC 4.2.1

Comment: Actually, the problem was really related to includes... Thanks, Naveen!